# Is my understanding of reversible and irreversible processes correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, reversibility

My question arises from the following exercise:

[image]

To answer the first question, since $PV = K$ as the process is isothermal, I can deduce that $P_2 = 2P_1$.

However, the next question made me closely consider what a reversible process means, and I've struggled to answer it a bit. In my interpretation, the case (b) has the temperature of the gas to increase, as there is a work done $W$ on the gas in $\Delta U = Q + W$ and quickly enough such that there is no $Q$ supplied immediately, meaning for a time $\Delta U \ne 0$. Since there is a temperature increase, the pressure would increase as well, on top of the fact that the gas is compressed, resulting in a higher change in pressure than in (a). However, I have trouble, I've realized, believing this did *not* happen in (a). I suppose it has to do with the definition of a reversible process (which is ultimately impossible to do perfectly), but I have trouble accepting that there was a change $dW$ in (a) that instantly met with $dQ$ to result in $\Delta U = 0$, since if there was any time at all $t$ where $dW$ was not canceled out instantly by the thermal reservoir supplying $dQ$ there would be a temperature increase. So, my mind has two hypotheses:

1) Thermal reservoir heat contribution $dQ$ requires a finite amount of time to supply heat to the gas depending on how large the change in volume was, but in the case of infinitesimals this time is negligible.

2) There is a certain, finite, amount of speed that which the volume is changed such that there will be a non-zero temperature change to the gas. This is achieved in (b).

Where am I thinking wrong? I'm sure my hypotheses are completely wrong but they arise from what I've gathered from thinking about the scenario, so my mistakes must arise in my understanding of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things where you have A becoming infinite while B approaches zero, and the product of A and B remains finite.  In a "nearly" reversible process where the boundary of the system is held in contact with an environment/reservoir at a constant temperature, the process is carried out slowly enough that the system temperature can be nearly equal to that of the reservoir throughout the process.  So the temperature is, at all times, only slightly different from that of the reservoir, and the heat transfer rate is very slow.  But, it requires a very large amount of time to carry out this slow process, so the integral of the heat transfer rate with respect to time is finite, and equal to the finite value Q.  This is just equal to the amount of work done.  The final temperature of the system is the same as the initial temperature (and that of the reservoir), so the change in internal energy is zero.

ADDENDUM

Let's assume that the compression is sufficiently slow for the behavior of the gas to be described by the ideal gas law in terms of the gas volume, pressure, and the average gas temperature $\bar{T}$Then, from a combination of the first law of thermodynamics and Newton's Law of Cooling, it follows that:

$$\frac{dU}{dt}=nC_v\frac{d\bar{T}}{dt}=-P\frac{dV}{dt}+\frac{dQ}{dt}=-\frac{nR\bar{T}}{V}\frac{dV}{dt}+k(T_0-\bar{T})\tag{1}$$

Suppose that, between time t = 0 and time $t=\tau$, the gas volume is made to change gradually with time according to the equation $$\ln(V)=\ln(V_i)+[\ln(V_f)-\ln(V_i)]\frac{t}{\tau}\tag{2}$$so that, at time t = 0, $V=V_i$ and at time $t=\tau$, $V=V_f$. The characteristic time $\tau$ is a measure of how quickly the volume is changed; large values of $\tau$ correspond to a more gradual rate of volume change and smaller values of $\tau$ correspond to a less gradual rate of volume change.

If we substitute Eqn. 2 into Eqn. 1, we obtain:

$$nC_v\frac{d\bar{T}}{dt}=-\frac{nR \ln{(V_f/V_i)}}{\tau}\bar{T}+k(T_0-\bar{T})\tag{3}$$
The solution to this equation, subject to the initial condition, $T=T_0$ @ t = 0 is found to be:

$$\bar{T}=T_0\left[\frac{k\tau}{(\alpha+k\tau)}+\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+k\tau)}e^{-\lambda\frac{t}{\tau}}\right]\tag{4}$$
where $\alpha=nR\ln{(V_f/V_i)}$ and $\lambda=\frac{(\alpha+k\tau)}{nC_v}$.

From this it follows that the rate of heat transfer from the reservoir to the gas is given by: $$\frac{dQ}{dt}=k(T_0-T)=\frac{k\alpha}{\alpha+k\tau}(1-e^{-\lambda\frac{t}{\tau}})\tag{5}$$
If we integrate this equation from time zero to time $t=\tau$, we obtain the total amount of heat added:
$$Q=\alpha T_0\frac{k\tau}{(\alpha+k\tau)}\left[1-\frac{nC_v}{(\alpha+k\tau)}(1-e^{-\frac{(\alpha+k\tau)}{nC_v}})\right]\tag{6}$$
As indicated previously, increasing the total time interval for the volume change $\tau$ is equivalent to slowing down the rate of volume change.  In the limit in which we make the rate of volume change infinitely slow (and the time required for the volume change infinitely long), $\tau \rightarrow \infty$, we obtain a cumulative heat addition of $$Q\rightarrow \alpha T_0=nRT_0\ln{(V_f/V_i)}\tag{7}$$
But this is exactly equal to the reversible work W done by the system on the surroundings.

So, in summary, even though the temperature difference between the system and surroundings (and the associated rate of heat transfer) is very small when we impose a very slow volume change, the time for the heat transfer becomes very large, and the amount of heat transferred is finite, and equal to the work.

Comment: Let me know if I understand you correctly: there are no "true" reversible processes, but a "near" reversible one is where we have a thermal reservoir at a constant temperature (likely low thermal conductivity) where the change in volume is so small that there is never much of an initial change of internal energy in the gas in the first place, but it is still done incrementally enough such that before the next increment $dV$ occurs, $T_1 = T_2$ of the gas. If that's correct, I have trouble understanding the last part of your question..

Comment: Which is namely, why is the heat transfer very slow, and why does that imply the integral of the heat transfer rate is finite? The integral of power with respect to time is work, so I can see why that's equal to work, but I don't understand the tie in to it being equal to $Q$ here.

Comment: Are you familiar with Newton's law of cooling?  If so, I can answer this question pretty easily.

Comment: I'm afraid not, but I know about Fourier's law.

Comment: Can you accept the approximation that the rate of heat transfer from the reservoir to the gas within the cylinder is proportional to the difference between the reservoir temperature and the gas temperature (averaged over the volume of the gas)?  That is $$\dot{Q}=k(T_0-\bar{T})$$ where k is a constant and $T_0$ is the reservoir temperature.

Comment: I could, yeah, as the hotter the reservoir is it should heat up quicker. Kind of like how it takes less time to get to a hot temperature if you were on the surface of the sun than if you were in a slightly warm bath?

Comment: OK.  I'm going to add an addendum to my answer to address this specific question.

Comment: I have modified the addendum to include the solution for the average gas temperature as a function of time, the rate of heat transfer, and the cumulative amount of heat transfer.  The relationships show that, even though the heat transfer rate becomes very small when we change the volume very gradually, the time over which the heat transfer occurs becomes very large, and the net effect is a finite amount of heat transfer equal to the reversible work.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a followup question.  Was my explanation not clear?  It took a lot of effort to work this out and document it.  A response would be nice.

Comment: Apologies! For some reason my reply never went through. I appreciate how thorough this addendum is, but I'm having trouble following it. I'll try and address my confusions: (a) Why are you justified saying in this case $\frac{dQ}{dt} = k(T_0- \bar T)$? (b) Is eq 2 not just some arbitrary gas expansion you've modeled? Why are we justified in using it to make meaningful conclusions? (c) I'm having trouble spotting how you made your substitution to get eq3.

Comment: The answer to (a) is that we are assuming that the rate of heat addition to the gas is proportional to the difference between the reservoir temperature and the gas temperature.  In a previous comment, you already accepted this approximation.  The answer to (b) is that we are manually imposing this monotonic expansion or compression on the gas as a function of time so we can see the effect of speeding up or slowing down the rate of volume change.  I chose this functional form to make the math easier.  To get Eqn. 3, all you have to do is differentiate Eqn. 2 with respect to time t.

Answer (score 0):

I think your thinking is right. However, in thermodynamics, we often assume a process is a quasi-statics, where the process is infinitely slow that, at each stage, the system is in equilibrium state i.e. no macroscopic change.

The other point I want to say adiabatic process is not about reversible process and irreversible process. This can cause confusion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second point?

Comment: $dS /ge /frac{/delta Q}T$ is for 2nd law. If it's reversible, the equality is used. And if it's adiabatic, entropy remains unchanged.